# How can I transform a PNG to a BMP without loosing quality

Tags: .net, image, png, bmp

This is a tricky one. First tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060442/png-to-bmp)  with an awful result

```
Image Dummy = Image.FromFile("image.png");   
Dummy.Save("image.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

[image] -----transforms into---->[image]

I have no idea what could be happening.
Any clues?

Comment: This is something to do with the transparency of your source image. I just tried it by saving your PNG with a white background and the conversion works fine. I have experimented with the PngBitmapDecoder class but I get the same results, so not sure of the solution as yet.

Comment: Do you need a program in .net, or is this just for one single conversion with the supplied image?

Comment: It's for a script that I'm writing so I a binary I could call from a .net process would do the trick as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both BMP and PNG are lossless, but PNG supports transparency while BMP doesn't. Because your original image has transparency, before converting it you should first ask yourself what you want to happen with the (semi)transparent pixels, and don't let the BMP encoder decide (it seems to take some weird decisions, BTW).

To remove the transparency amounts, conceptually, to add some opaque background (white or black, normally - in your case, white). For doing that in C#, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618259/remove-transparency-in-images-with-c-sharp)